# Invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ on OSX 10.8

Tags: c++, macos, flags, xcodebuild, node-gyp

I am compiling through `node-gyp` a Node.JS package written in C++. When I compile it I receive the following error: `clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)`. I'm running on OSX 10.8, and I have installed the XCode Command Line Tools. This is the file used by node-gyp to compile the package:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "package_name",

      'type': 'executable',

      'xcode_settings': {
        'OTHER_CFLAGS': [
          "-std=c++11",
          "-stdlib=libc++"
        ],
      },

      "sources": [ "package_src.cpp" ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically it specifies the target of the compilation, the type and the flags, as well as the sources.

Any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked, but for Googlers arriving at this rather Google-juicey question after encountering this error message while trying to install something via a package manager: you can probably fix it with some environment variables. Either do `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 your_install_command` to tell Clang to use a later deployment target, or install a real version of GCC (the `gcc` binary you've got is actually Clang), e.g. with `brew install gcc`, and tell `make` to use it via the `CC` and/or `CXX` environment variables - e.g. `CC=gcc-9 CXX=g++-9 your_install_command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what worked for you, @drewish, but this is how I got it to work:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "package_name",

      'type': 'executable',

      'xcode_settings': {
        'OTHER_CFLAGS': [
          "-std=c++11",
      "-stdlib=libc++",
      "-mmacosx-version-min=10.7"
        ],
      },

      "sources": [ "overcpu.cpp" ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Specifying `"-mmacosx-version-min=10.7"` ends up putting it in along with the "-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" that node-gyp inserts by default. My recollection is that the 10.5 ends up at the end and overrides the first one.

Comment: May i know the location of this file?

Comment: More info here @NarendraSoni https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1574

Answer (score 8):

Whilst you got OS X 10.8 clang will try to build it so that it can be run on other older OS X versions too. Now since `-stdlib=libc++` requires a minimum version of 10.7 it won't compile it unless you explicitly tell it that you'll use 10.7 (or higher) as the deployment target by specifying

```
'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '10.7'
```

inside the `xcode_settings`.

In your case the complete settings should look like:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "package_name",

      'type': 'executable',

      'xcode_settings': {
        'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '10.7',

        'OTHER_CFLAGS': [
          "-std=c++11",
          "-stdlib=libc++"
        ],
      },

      "sources": [ "package_src.cpp" ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah that works nicely. I was trying to pass `'-mmacosx-version-min=10.7'` in and it was concatenating it on, rather than replacing the existing 10.5 flag.